# How to insert item from ref object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at node.js, mongodb and mongoose. I have a bit problem on ref object on mongoose.

This is my code

admin.js

```
router.post('/accounts/show_account/team/add_member/:account_id/:team_id', function(req,res){

    var account_id = req.params.account_id;
    var team_id = req.params.team_id;

    var full_name = req.body.full_name;
    var position = req.body.position;
    var dateStarted = req.body.dateStarted;

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        // res.render('register',{errors:errors});
        console.log('errors');
    } else{
        var newMember = new Members({

            full_name : full_name,
            position : position,
            dateStarted : dateStarted

        });

        newMember.save(function(err,member){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(member);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

model.js -> schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MemberSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    full_name : {
        type: String
    },
    current_position : {
        type: String
    },
    dateStarted : {
        type: String
    },
    is_admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default : false
    }
});

var member = module.exports = mongoose.model('Members', MemberSchema);
module.exports.createMember = function(newMember, callback){

    newMember.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

team.js -> team schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TeamSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    team_name: {
        type: String
    },
    date_created: {
        type: Date
    },
    members: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : member
    }]
});




var Team = module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);



module.exports.createTeam = function(newTeam, callback){

    newTeam.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

I am trying to join the team schema and the member schema but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: In `ref` you should enter the name of the `"Members"` model

Comment: I think I already added the "Members" model on ref. Can you point me out whats my error?

Comment: You entered the reference to the Members model. Instead just put the name of the model as a string. `ref: 'Members'`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the schema related name as a string

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TeamSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    team_name: {
        type: String
    },
    date_created: {
        type: Date
    },
    members: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Members"
    }]
});




var Team = module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);



module.exports.createTeam = function(newTeam, callback){

    newTeam.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

Now you can "join" your schemas using `[populate][1]` function when you doing a serch.

If you need insert new *Members* inside *TeamSchema* document just add a  *_id* of  new *member*

```
    var newMebers = new Members({...});

    newMembers.save()
     .then(function(newMember){
         return TeamSchema.findById(<TeamId>,
          {$push:{members:newMember._id});
       })
       .catch(function(err){ console.error(err)});
```